# Listview is losing data on postback ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I am trying to update the whole list by once by using a button but in code behind I am losing the data of the list items it returns null although it has the items. Please help me in this manner. my code is below

**aspx**

```html
<asp:ListView ID="ProjectsList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProjectId" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" ViewStateMode="Enabled"> 

    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #FFF8DC;">
            <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectId") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="SchoolIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SchoolId") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="FairIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FairId") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="CategoryIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="BalanceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Balance") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:CheckBox ID="FinalistCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Finalist") %>' Enabled="true" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectStatusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectStatus") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
            <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectId") %>' /></td>
            <td>asp:Label ID="SchoolIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SchoolId") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="FairIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FairId") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="CategoryIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="BalanceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Balance") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:CheckBox ID="FinalistCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Finalist") %>' Enabled="true" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectStatusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectStatus") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                            <th runat="server">ProjectId</th>
                            <th id="Th1" runat="server">SchoolId</th>
                            <th id="Th2" runat="server">FairId</th>
                            <th id="Th3" runat="server">CategoryId</th>
                            <th runat="server">Title</th>
                            <th id="Th4" runat="server">Balance</th>
                            <th runat="server">Finalist</th>
                            <th runat="server">ProjectStatus</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=MyEntity" DefaultContainerName="MyEntity" EnableFlattening="False" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Projects">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
<asp:Button ID="FinalistButton" runat="server" Text="Finalist" OnClick="FinalistButton_Click" CssClass="imageButtonStyle" />
```

and my aspx.cs...

```cs
protected void FinalistButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //here I can have all the items but there is no value
    foreach (ListViewItem item in ProjectsList.Items) 
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            CheckBox final = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("Finalist");
            TextBox proidText = (TextBox)item.FindControl("ProjectId");
            int proId = Convert.ToInt32(proidText.Text);
            if (final.Checked)  
            {
                //some code
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: List items are null?  or just empty (0 count)?  I've never really seen a "null" list view before in asp.net.  Also, is the list view displaying items on screen before submit?

Comment: God I hate nested tables! And MS take that to a whole new level!

Comment: Note: You're likely getting an exception due to the look-up for "Finalist" failing.  You have no controls with an ID of "Finalist".  Also, `ListItem` controls don't generally contain many other controls under them...

Comment: Just in case: in your Page_Load event, you are using if (!Page.IsPostback()).  That one gets me every time.

Comment: I am using if(!Page.IsPostBack()) in my page_load

Comment: ListView brings all the controls as many as how many items that I have in the list however the data part is null

Comment: By the way, the listview shows all data before I click on the button

Answer (score 0):

To insert or update data, the templates < InsertItemTemplate> and/or < EditItemTemplate> should be included, maybe they're missing. Templates < ItemTemplate> and < AlternateItemTemplate> are just used to show data. To change templates, add some command buttons. And you use Bind instead of Eval

You have a walkthrough at the following link, not very good, though. Maybe you can find a better example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515103.aspx